# Boundaries of noncompact contractible manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

It is known that a manifold $B$ bounds a compact contractible topological manifold if and only if $B$ is a homology sphere. The "only if" direction follows by excising a small ball in the interior of the contractible manifold, and noting that its boundary sphere has the same homology as $B$ by Poincare duality. The "if" direction is due to Freedman in dimension $3$ and to Kervaire in dimensions $>3$.

**Question.** Is there a characterization of boundaries of
*noncompact* contractible manifolds?

Note that if $B$ is a boundary component of a contractible $n$-manifold $W$, then
the following holds.

1. If $B$ is compact, then $W$ is compact and $\partial W=B$. 
   (If $V$ denotes the union of $B$ and the interior of $W$, then
   the long exact sequence of the pair gives $H_{n-1}(B)\cong H_{n}(V,B)$ 
   and Poincare duality gives implies that $H_{n-1}(B)$ is nontrivial,
   and hence so is $H_{n}(V,B)\cong H^0_c(V)$ which is only possible 
   if $V$ is compact.)
2. $B$ is stably parallelizable (because $W$ is parallelizable).
3. If $U$ is a proper open subset of $B$, then $U$ bounds a noncompact contractible manifold, namely, $U\cup\mathrm{Int}(W)$.
4. The product of $B$ with any open contractible manifold bounds a noncompact contractible manifold.
5. If $B'$ bounds a contractible manifold $W'$, then the connected sum
   $B\# B'$ bounds a contractible manifold, namely, the boundary connected sum of $W$, $W'$.

The above question may be too hard, so I would be happy with any addition to 1--5.

Comment: 6. Intersection products in $B$ are trivial.

Comment: By 3, $B$ can have the homotopy type of any finite 
complex, by taking a thickening of some embedding in 
Euclidian space. So for example any $k$ dim'l complex has 
the homotopy type of a $n=2k+1$  manifold which is the boundary
of a contractible $n+1$ manifold.

Comment: @Tom, I am struggling to make the notion of an intersection product precise. Is triviality of the intersection product based on the fact that $B$ has trivial normal bundle in $W$, or does the contractibility of $W$ get used?

Comment: Every cycle in $B$ is the boundary of a chain in $W$. So basically given a $p$-cycle and an $(n-p-1)$-cycle in $B$ their intersection is the boundary of the intersection of a $(p+1)$-chain and an $(n-p)$-chain in $W$, so the boundary of a $1$-chain, so a homologically trivial $0$-chain. To make this rigorous I guess you would need to say something about Poincare duality and compactly supported cohomology.

Comment: In particular I am referring to intersection numbers, not to the ring structure on homology.

Comment: @Tom, oh, and the intersection number is trivial because the $0$-cycle is a boundary, so its points come in pairs with opposite signs, and cancel. Thank you for suggesting this!. I think this "intersection product" is Poincare dual to the cup product, as discussed in Dold's "Algebraic Topology", section VIII.13.

Comment: Maybe the answer is any open subset of a homology sphere? Linking numbers vanish also.  I can't see how to find a compact $n$-manifold with boundary $M$ whose interior bounds a contractible manifold but which doesn't embed in a homology $n$-sphere. For $n=3$, it seems like you can add 2-handles to $M$ to get a homology ball, and perhaps in higher dimensions you could add handles to get a homology ball.

Comment: @Paul, linking numbers do not vanish, not even in the sphere bounding a disk. I am not sure whether "open subsets of homology spheres" is the answer. Certainly, $B\times\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^{2n-1}$:
just embed $B$ properly in $\mathbb R^{2n-1}$ and note that the normal bundle is trivial by 2. But I cannot see why $B$ itself would be homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^{2n-1}$. Would not it be like showing that any open contractible manifold has a manifold compactification (which is surely false)? 
 

Comment: @Igor: I meant the $Q/Z$ valued linking form on the torsion homology classes.  I was thinking a warm up problem is to determine which $B=$interior$(M)$, $M$ compact, are boundaries, and suggesting maybe all such embed as codim 0 submanifolds of a homology sphere.  
 

Comment: Tom's comment on intersection product together with classification of noncompact 2-manifolds implies that if $B$ has dimension $2$, then it is homeomorphic to an open subset of $S^2$, and clearly any open subset of $S^2$ occurs as $B$. Indeed, if the surface is not planar, then it contains a handle, and hence there are two curves that only intersect once.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but only a vague suggestion: Instead of trying to embed $B$ in a homology (n-1)-manifold, one can try to embed it in a homology sphere which is also a homology (n-1)-manifold. This might be easier. This situation could be similar to Mladen Bestvina's theorems on ideal boundaries of hyperbolic PD(n) groups. One approach would be to construct a suitable Gromov-hyperbolic metric on $W$ so that $B$ is a part of the ideal boundary. Alternatively, one can try to imitate Bestvina's arguments without having a metric (or, instead, using a weaker structure a la John Roe). 

Comment: Recall that Bestvina proved in 1996 that a hyperbolic group $G$ is a $PD(n)$ group if and only if its ideal boundary is a homology manifold which is also a homology sphere (of dimension n-1 of course). One can also ask an absolute version of your question in the hyperbolic context: Suppose $W$ is contractible $n$-manifold. Does $W$ admit a bounded geometry hyperbolic metric so that the ideal boundary is a homology manifold/homology sphere (of dimension n-1)? No group is involved here, just pure geometry.  

Comment: A remark: The approach I suggested could work only for $n\ge 4$, since every homology 2-sphere is homeomorphic to the usual sphere. But for $n\ge 4$ I do not see any obvious obstructions. 

Comment: Misha, thank you for bringing geometry into the game. Yet I do not see how this gives an embedding of the boundary of $W$ into the ideal boundary of (a hyperbolic metric on) the interior of $W$. The ideal boundary is not necessarily the largest compactification. Say start with a compact contractible manifold whose boundary is a homology sphere $B$, remove a proper closed subset of $B$, and try to use your idea to embed what is left in a homology manifold; this looks hard.

Comment: Igor, of course,  one has to construct a Gromov-hyperbolic metric on $W$ "relative" to $B$, so that $B$ embeds. The difficulty with my approach, I think, is in two absolute cases: (1) constructing a Gromov-hyperbolic metric on $W$ so that the entire boundary is a homology sphere; (2) Given a compact contractible manifold $W$ with boundary $B$, construct a metric on $W$ so that $B$ is the ideal boundary. Part (2), I think, is quite doable and mildly interesting.  
Part (1), I think, is difficult, if not impossible. 

Comment: Could you please tell me a source of the proof of $H^k_\textbf{c}(M)\cong H_{n-k}(M,\partial M)$, where $n=\dim M$?

Comment: @User See theorem 11.3 in Massey "Homology and cohomology theory", or the section on Poincare duality in Bredon's "Sheaf theory".  There two references involve (co)homology of general spaces and may be hard for a beginner. Alternatively, solve exercise 35 in section 33 in Hatcher's "Algebraic topology".